# What it is the solution for this problem Laravel Action

Tags: laravel

```
Action App\Http\Controllers\AdminController@dbTanger not defined.
```

And this is My AdminController

```
public function dbTanger() {
        $data = Db::table('ressos')  
        ->where('secteur','Services')
        ->get();
        
    return view('backend.layouts.admin.typeFilterTanger',compact('data','pagi'));
      }
```

And this is the view

```
 <div class="Filter">
          <p>Filter Using Ville</p>
          <a href="{{ action('AdminController@dbTanger') }}">Tanger-Asilah</a>
 </div>
```

so if anyone can help me please
and thank you all

Comment: Welcome to SO ... did you define a route for this action?

Answer (score 1):

Since Laravel 9, the default Controller namespace has not been included in the `RouteServiceProvider` so you need to be explicit about where to locate controllers (or add the default namespace to your RouteServiceProvider).

What you can do is the following:

```
{{ action('\App\Http\Controllers\AdminController@dbTanger') }}
```

However, I would recommend using the `route` helper in conjunction with named routes as this is easier to manage should files change or move location in the future.

```
Route::get('/admin/dbTanger', [AdminController::class, 'dbTanger'])->name('admin.dbTanger');
```

Then use it as follows:

```
{{ route('admin.dbTanger') }}
```

The outcome is the same, just easier to manage and maintain long-term.

Comment: the error says it is looking for the Controller `App\Http\Controllers\AdminController@...` so the namespace is there ... if it wasn't it would only be looking for `AdminController@...` without any namespace

Answer (score 0):

That error would mean you didn't define a route to this action so there is nothing in the route collection to be found for that action.

Define a route for this action and you would be able to use that `action` helper to create a URL to a route that uses this action.

Answer (score -1):

Welcome to stack-overflow,

First you should learn the "basic routing" in laravel

[Laravel Routing](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/routing)